# bash history truncated after sudo su

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

I modified the .bashrc file to make the .bash_history file with "infinite" size and its working only when I sudo su to use root on teriminal, the history file is truncated back to the default 2000 line size 
any suggestions to solve this please ?

from my **.bashrc** file :

```
 export HISTFILESIZE=
 export HISTSIZE=
 export HISTFILE=~/.bash_infinite_history
 PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. Your question *may* be appropriate on other SE sites such as [Unix.se]. Check their help before posting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `sudo su` (or `sudo -i`), you are switching users.

Your personal user has `HISTSIZE` set, but the user you are becoming (in this case, `root`) does not.

If you want, you can set the `HISTSIZE` for `root` in his config file (for example, `/root/.bashrc`), but **the histories will be separate**.

Comment: they were separated at first, after the modifications above. the user "root" also became using the same file. but instead of adding history in definitely . it doesn't go after 2000 lines